# thymeleaf fragments include

Tags: include, thymeleaf

I keep getting "Error resolving template "fragments/common", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers". The path of common.html file is correct, fragments->common.html. My folder structure:

-- WEB-INF

---- templates

------ fragments

-------- common.html

------ index.html

Any help or pointers?

Comment: Can you put your thymeleaf bean configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I found the problem. Wrong syntax, the error message says it all. I was using common.html, the template name included in include statement is incorrect.

Comment: can you elaborate on this? I'm having the same error using thymeleaf layout dialect and don't understand why its happening considering it's pointing where it should be.

Comment: include "fragments/common.html" instead of "fragments/common"

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm late to the party but I thought I'd share what I'm doing which to me seemed somewhat easier.

I use a java config class to configure thymeleaf and I use the template alias to make it easier:

```
resolver.addTemplateAlias("footerTemplate","templates/footer");
```

Then I can simple do something like:

```
<div th:include="footerTemplate :: copy"></div>
```

assuming you have your suffix and prefix setup correctly.